# SVN: How can I list all the files in a changelist in Subversion?

Tags: svn, command-line

How can a get a list of files in an SVN changelist with NO information except the file list?

I want a listing of files in a changelist in a format that I can use in Bash's $(). I start with `svn st --cl 3011`, which lists the files but with a lot of extra junk:

> Performing status on external item at 'foo'
>
> ?   foo/bar
>
> Performating status on external item at 'foo/bar'
>
> --- Changelist '3011':
>
> M   src/math/math.cc
>
> A   src/math/determinant.cc
>
> A   src/math/determinant.h
>
> M   src/math/matrix.h

That's a lot of info to try and get sed or awk to parse through, and I'm worried I'll mess it up and end up missing a file in the changelist or adding stuff that's not in the changelist. -q doesn't help much.

Is there any way get svn to just give me `src/math/math.cc src/math/determinant.cc src/math/determinant.h src/math/matrix.h`?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 6):

This will do:

```
svn st --changelist 3011 | grep -v Changelist | cut -b 3-
```

`svn st --changelist` will print the name of the changelist plus the status of the files and the file names:

```
--- Changelist 'cl_name':
M       file1
A       file2
```

Now you edit this by first deleting the first line with a "grep -v Changelist", which deletes the line with the word Changelist. Then do a "cut -b 3-" to delete the first few characters of each line.

With the full command, you get:

```
 file1
 file2
```

Answer (score 3):

### Use --ignore-externals and --cl!

You don't need to use any external tools like `grep` or `awk`. This is actually pretty simple!

The command `--ignore-externals` removes all the extra junk from the `svn status` call, and you can easily merge that with `--cl` parameter too:

```
svn st --ignore-externals --cl "Changelist Name"
```

That will ignore all externals, and then give you just the files in the changelist you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going one directory at a time you can do per directory:

`svn status lib | awk '{print $2}'`

Where you swap out lib for the dir in question.

Comment: Unfortunately, again, the "--- Changelist '3510':" will print, as will some of the "Performing status on external item"s -- and the names of the external items.

Comment: @Ian Weird. Must be my version (visualSVN 1.6.12) as when I run it, I only get filenames.

Comment: I think it's our weird SVN setup. Most SVN depots don't have 'external' items, so you don't see that output.

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know there is no direct way (only with svn arguments) to do what you want. However, you can rely on output of **svn stat -v**, and on that path starts from 41 position.
For only immidiates the following perl one-liner do the task:

```
perl -e "@st=`svn stat -v -N`;foreach $l (@st){print substr($l,41);}"
```

For recursive status just remove -N from svn arguments.

In addition to printing out all contents of the directoty you may want to separate modified files, files not under svn, by revision, etc. In this case you can easily modify my above script using the **substr(0,1)** - first char of each output. For example, the following one-liner will output list of only modified files:

```
perl -e "@st=`svn stat -v -N`;foreach $l (@st){print substr($l,41) if substr($l,0,1) eq "M";}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. svn stat -v -cl 3011 still gets extra output, like "Performing status on external item at 'foo'", and "--- Changelist '3510':". Plus, starting at column 28, there is sometimes an email address (not sure what it means); if it's long enough, it pushes the filename over past column 41. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

svn log -r <revision_number> -v